# Does null coalescing operator call a function twice?

Tags: php, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

The null coalescing operator (`??`) returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, and otherwise returns its second operand.

If the first operand is a function or method call, does the operator call the function call twice?

As an example, say the function `get_name()` returns a string value or null.

`$name = get_name() ?? 'no name found';`

So is `get_name()` called once and the value stored ready to assign it to the variable (`$name`) or when the `??` is activated due to the function returning a value that is true for `isset()`, does `??` call on the first operand a second time to get the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only called once.

This is quite easy to see if you add a side effect to your function, such as printing, e.g.:

```
<?php
function get_name() {
    print("get_name() was called\n");
    return "somestring";
}

$name = get_name() ?? 'no name found';
print($name);
?>
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7284c0f965846d3e348a004fecc0b2f87ccacd95)**

Comment: Nice test! simple really too, once you see someone suggest it. Thanks

Comment: You can use `__FUNCTION__` or `__METHOD__` constants to get the name of the current function.  Method will display the class `class::method`. :)  For example `print __FUNCTION__."() was called\n";`